# rails, rspec: No flash message on page, when testing feature

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Rails 4.2, rspec 3.4.0

When i create 'question' by hands, flash notice is in the place. But when i go with rspec, flash hash is empty and notice isn't exist. I tried to run rails server in test environment to ensure all works when doing manually. It is. My recent project's tests work well with same gemset. So i developed this is rspec fault. And now i don't know where to go.

**question_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @question = Question.new(question_params)

  if @question.save
    flash[:notice] = t('question.created')
    redirect_to @question
  else
    flash[:alert] = t('question.not_created')
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

**features/creating_questions_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature 'Creating Questions' do
  before do
    visit '/'
    click_link 'English'
  end
  scenario "can create question" do
    fill_in 'question_body', with: 'What is this?'
    click_button t('question.create')
    expect(page).to have_content(t 'question.created')
  end
```

**rspec output**

```
Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content(t 'question.created')
  expected to find text "Question has been created." in "Home Sign in Sign 
  up Русский English What is this?
```

**layout**

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <div class='flash' id='<%= key %>'>
    <%= value %>
  </div> <% end %>

<%= yield %>
```

Comment: Your spec is going to the home page; is question creation really what happens when you click "English"?

Comment: My root is questions' index. 'English' link changes locale to 'en'. And all works well when i do it as a user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after long research i have found the answer.

To implement i18n in my project i used 138 railscast by Ryan Bates. From there i took this function:

**application_controller.rb**

```
def default_url_options(options={})
  {:host => "localhost:3000",
   :locale => I18n.locale}
end
```

String `:host => "localhost:3000"` causes the trouble . Comment it and viola! - all works fine again